# Hadoop: what should be mapped and what should be reduced?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

This is my first time using map/reduce. I want to write a program that processes a large log file. For example, if I was processing a log file that had records consisting of {Student, College, and GPA}, and wanted to sort all students by college, what would be the 'map' part and what would be the 'reduce' part? I am having some difficulty with the concept, despite having gone over a number of tutorials and examples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking, Hadoop MapReduce treats everything as key-value pairs; you just need to define what the keys are and what the values are.  The signatures of map and reduce are

```
map: (K1 x V1) -> (K2 x V2) list
reduce: (K2 x V2) list -> (K3 x V3) list
```

with sorting taking place on K2 values in the intermediate shuffle phase between map and reduce.

If your inputs are of the form

```
Student x (College x GPA)
```

Then your mapper should do nothing more than get the College values to the key:

```
map: (s, c, g) -> [(c, s, g)]
```

with college as the new key, Hadoop will sort by college for you.  Your reducer then, is just a plain old "identity reducer."

If you are carrying out a sorting operation in practice (that is, this isn't a homework problem), then check out [Hive](http://hive.apache.org), or [Pig](http://pig.apache.org).  These systems drastically simplify these kinds of tasks.  Sorting on a particular column becomes quite trivial.  However, it is always educational to write, say, a hadoop streaming job for tasks like the one you identified here, to give you a better understanding of mappers and reducers.

Comment: The input data has to be sampled and a custom partition written to send a key range to a particular reducer. Then the output of the N reducers just need to be concatenated.

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo has [sorted](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/posts/2009/05/hadoop_sorts_a_petabyte_in_162/) Peta and Tera Bytes of data. Others (including [Google](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2011/09/sorting-petabytes-with-mapreduce-next.html)) do it on a regular basis, you can search for the sort benchmarks on the internet. Yahoo has published a [paper](http://www.hpl.hp.com/hosted/sortbenchmark/YahooHadoop.pdf) on how they have done it.

Ray's approach has to be modified a bit to get the final output sorted. The input data has to be sampled and a custom partition written to send a key range to a particular reducer. Then the output of the N reducers just need to be concatenated. The Yahoo paper explains this is more detail.

The 'org.apache.hadoop.examples.terasort' package has sample code for sorting data.

If you are new to MapReduce I suggest watching the following videos. They are a bit lengthy, but are worth.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjPBkvYh-ss
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vD6PUdf3Js
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Eib_H_zCEY
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZDybXl212Q
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BT-piFBP4fE

**Edit:** Found some more information at the Cloudera blog [here](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2008/12/whats-new-in-hadoop-core-019/). There are some built-in classes to make sorting easier.

> Total order partitions [HADOOP-3019](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3019). As a spin-off from the TeraSort record, Hadoop now has library classes for efficiently producing a globally sorted output. InputSampler is used to sample a subset of the input data, and then TotalOrderPartitioner is used to partition the map outputs into approximately equal-sized partitions. Very neat stuff — well worth a look, even if you don’t need to use it.