# Hadoop Sort map and reduce key value

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

If I had a file with random integers on each line and wanted to sort the file using Hadoop, what would my mapper and reducer's input/output key and value be?

Comment: A detailed explanation is posted at the link below [how-to-produce-sorted-file-using-hadoop](http://sarveshspn.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-produce-sorted-file-using-hadoop.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo has [sorted](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/posts/2009/05/hadoop_sorts_a_petabyte_in_162/) Peta and Tera Bytes of data. Others (including [Google](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2011/09/sorting-petabytes-with-mapreduce-next.html)) do it on a regular basis, you can search for the sort benchmarks on the internet. Yahoo has published a [paper](http://www.hpl.hp.com/hosted/sortbenchmark/YahooHadoop.pdf) on how they have done it.

The 'org.apache.hadoop.examples.terasort' package has sample code for sorting data.

Found some more information at the Cloudera blog [here](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2008/12/whats-new-in-hadoop-core-019/). There are some built-in classes to make sorting easier.

> Total order partitions [HADOOP-3019](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3019). As a spin-off from the TeraSort record, Hadoop now has library classes for efficiently producing a globally sorted output. InputSampler is used to sample a subset of the input data, and then TotalOrderPartitioner is used to partition the map outputs into approximately equal-sized partitions. Very neat stuff — well worth a look, even if you don’t need to use it.

You can also find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607569/hadoop-what-should-be-mapped-and-what-should-be-reduced).

Comment: I'm new to Hadoop, can you be more specific on what the mapper and reducer's key/value would be for sorting a file described above?

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607569/hadoop-what-should-be-mapped-and-what-should-be-reduced) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

A more theoretical answer : Consider the different sorting algorithms (quick sort, merge sort, bubble sort, etc.... ) .

Because of the fact that we know you can merge two sorted lists in linear time , it is quite simple to parallelize any sorting algorithm by putting a "merge" step on top of it.  Thus, there are a wide range of options which you could use to accomplish this task.

The terasort is much smarter than this, however, because simply splitting and merging won't solve all your problems.... your final "merge" step corresponds to a massive reduce step when you have alot of splits.